# Why would you use lambda instead of def?

Tags: python, lambda

Is there any reason that will make you use:

```
add2 = lambda n: n+2
```

instead of :

```
def add2(n): return n+2
```

I tend to prefer the `def` way but every now and then I see the `lambda` way being used.

EDIT :
The question is not about `lambda` as unnamed function, but about lambda as a *named* function.

There is a good answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134626/which-is-more-preferable-to-use-in-python-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions).

Comment: No need to change your preference. ;) I use lambda for very short functions exclusively, if ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lambda` is nice for small, *unnamed* functions but in this case it would serve no purpose other than make functionalists happy.

Comment: How about currying, and other common functional programming tasks? Yes, it makes functionalists happy. As they should, since it's one of the major branches of programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a lambda for throwaway functions I'm going to use only in one place, for example as an argument to a function.  This keeps the logic together and avoids filling the namespace with function names I don't need.

For example, I think

```
map(lambda x: x * 2,xrange(1,10))
```

is neater than:

```
def bytwo(x):
    return x * 2

map(bytwo,xrange(1,10))
```

Comment: `lambda` has been in Python much much longer than list comprehensions, etc. The equivalent `[ x*2 for x in xrange(1,10) ]` runs faster than the map, so many places where `lambda` was a good solution are falling from favour

Answer (score 1):

Guido Van Rossum (the creator of Python) prefers def over lambdas (lambdas only made it to Python 3.0 at the last [moment](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208549)) and there is nothing you can't do with def that you can do with lambdas.

People who like the functional programming paradigm seem to prefer them. Some times using an anonymous function (that you can create with a lambda expression) gives more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

I recall [David Mertz writing](http://gnosis.cx/publish/tech_index_cp.html) that he preferred to use the form `add2 = lambda n: n+2` because it emphasised that add2 is a pure function that has no side effects.  However I think 99% of Python programmers would use the `def` statement and only use lambda for anonymous functions, since that is what it is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

One place you can't use `def` is in expressions: A `def` is a statement. So that is about the only place I'd use `lambda`.