# Memory-friendly way to add a field to a structured ndarray — without duplicating data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, structured-array

To add a field to a structured numpy array, it is quite simply to create a new array with a new dtype, copy over the old fields, and add the new field.  However, I need to do this for an array that takes a lot of memory, and I would rather not duplicate all of it.  Both my own implementation and the (slow) implementation in `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields` duplicate memory.

Is there a way to add a field to a structured `ndarray`, without duplicating memory?  That means, either a way that avoids creating a new `ndarray`, *or* a way to create a new `ndarray` that points to the same data as the old?

Solutions that do duplicate RAM:

- [Adding a field to a structured numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array)
- [Adding a field to a structured numpy array (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288736/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-2)
- [Adding a field to a structured numpy array (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413947/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-3)

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079175/how-to-remove-a-column-from-a-structured-numpy-array-without-copying-it) where the challenge is to *remove*, not add, fields.  The solution uses a view, which should work for a subset of the original data, but I'm not sure if it can be amended when I rather want to *add* fields.

Comment: If your array is a view on a buffer of which the last half is not used, you might be able to allocate the extra fields in the last half (rather than adjacent to their existing row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A structured array is stored, like a regular one, as a contiguous buffer of bytes, one record following the previous.  The records are, thus, a bit like the last dimension of a multidimensional array.  You can't add a column to a 2d array without making a new array via concatenation.

Adding a field, say `I4` dtype to dtype that is, say, 20 bytes long, means changing the record (element) length to 24, i.e. adding 4 bytes to the buffer every 20th byte.  `numpy` can't do that without making a new data buffer and copying values from the old (and the new).

Actually even if we were talking about adding a new record to the array, i.e. concatenating on a new array, it would still require creating a new data buffer.  Arrays are fixed sized.

Fields in a structured array are not like objects in a list or a dictionary.  You can't add a field by just adding a pointer to an object elsewhere in memory.

Maybe you should be using a dictionary, with `item` being an array.  Then you can freely add a key/item without copying the existing ones.  But then access by 'rows' will be slow.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I need a different approach then.  Perhaps I could cut the big array in N pieces, adding fields to the smaller pieces one at a time, so that I still copy everything, but not all at once, thus limiting peak memory usage.

Comment: Still, it should be possible to do it in a memory friendly way without duplicating data. It could copy data to a new array and grow the new array size while simultaneously decreasing the old array size.

Comment: Each 'grow' and 'decrease' requires a data copy.  Don't worry about 'memory friendly' unless it is really hurting execution times or you get 'memory error' problems.  But don't conflate those two problems.