# Delete numpy column by name

Tags: python, numpy

I created a numpy array from csv by

```
dtest = np.genfromtxt('data/test.csv', delimiter=",", names = True)
```

The data has 200 columns named 'name', 'id', and so on.
I'm trying to delete the 'id' column.

Can I do that using the name of the column?

Comment: Have you had a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642730/how-to-delete-columns-in-numpy-array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you have a comprehensive answer but this is another that I just put together.

```
import numpy as np
```

### For some sample data file:

```
test1.csv = 
a   b   c   id
0   1   2   3
4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11
```

### Import using `genfromtxt`:

```
d = np.genfromtxt('test1.csv', delimiter="\t", names = True)

d
> array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0), (8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0)], 
  dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('id', '<f8')])
```

### Return a single column from your array by doing:

```
d['a']
> array([ 0.,  4.,  8.])
```

To delete the column by the name 'id' you can do the following:

### Return a list of the column names by writing:

```
list(d.dtype.names)
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'id']
```

### Create a new numpy array by returning only those columns not equal to the string `id`.

Use a list comprehension to return a new list without your 'id' string:

```
[b for b in list(d.dtype.names) if b != 'id']
> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

### Combine to give:

```
d_new = d[[b for b in list(d.dtype.names) if b != 'id']]

> array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0), (8.0, 9.0, 10.0)], 
  dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

### This returns the array:

```
a   b   c
0   1   2
4   5   6
8   9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the proposed duplicate, [How do you remove a column from a structured numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575878/how-do-you-remove-a-column-from-a-structured-numpy-array)
show how to reference a subset of the fields of a structured array.  That may be what you want, but it has a potential problem, which I'll illustrate in a bit.

Start with a small sample csv 'file':

```
In [32]: txt=b"""a,id,b,c,d,e
    ...: a1, 3, 0,0,0,0.1
    ...: b2, 4, 1,2,3,4.4
    ...: """
In [33]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None)
In [34]: data
Out[34]: 
array([(b'a1', 3, 0, 0, 0,  0.1), 
       (b'b2', 4, 1, 2, 3,  4.4)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('id', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<f8')])
```

### Multifield selection

I can get a 'view' of a subset of the fields with a field name list.  The 'duplicate' showed how to construct such a list from the `data.dtype.names`.  Here I'll just type it in, omitting the 'id' name.

```
In [35]: subd=data[['a','b','c','d']]
In [36]: subd
Out[36]: 
array([(b'a1', 0, 0, 0), (b'b2', 1, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')])
```

The problem is that this isn't regular 'view'. It's fine for reading, but any attempt to write to the subset, raises a warning.

```
In [37]: subd[0]['b'] = 3
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a structured
array. This code will likely break in a future numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Making a subset copy is ok.  But changes to `subd` won't affect `data`.

```
In [38]: subd=data[['a','b','c','d']].copy()
In [39]: subd[0]['b'] = 3
In [40]: subd
Out[40]: 
array([(b'a1', 3, 0, 0), (b'b2', 1, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')])
```

A simple way to delete the `ith` field name from the indexing list:

```
In [60]: subnames = list(data.dtype.names)   # list so its mutable
In [61]: subnames
Out[61]: ['a', 'id', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
In [62]: del subnames[1]
```

### usecols

Since you are reading this array from the `csv`, you could use `usecols` to load everything but the 'id' column

Since you have a large number of columns it would easist to do something like:

```
In [42]: col=list(range(6)); del col[1]
In [43]: col
Out[43]: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [44]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None,usecols=col)
Out[44]: 
array([(b'a1', 0, 0, 0,  0.1), (b'b2', 1, 2, 3,  4.4)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<f8')])
```

### recfunctions

There's a library of functions that can help manipulate structured arrays

```
In [45]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [47]: rf.drop_fields(data, ['id'])
Out[47]: 
array([(b'a1', 0, 0, 0,  0.1), (b'b2', 1, 2, 3,  4.4)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<f8')])
```

Most functions in this group work by constructing a 'blank' array with the target `dtype`, and then copying values, by field, from the source to the target.

### field copy

Here's the field copy approach used in `recfunctions`:

```
In [65]: data.dtype.descr  # dtype description as list of tuples
Out[65]: 
[('a', '|S2'),
 ('id', '<i4'),
 ('b', '<i4'),
 ('c', '<i4'),
 ('d', '<i4'),
 ('e', '<f8')]
In [66]: desc=data.dtype.descr
In [67]: del desc[1]                # remove one field
In [68]: res = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=desc)  # target
In [69]: res
Out[69]: 
array([(b'', 0, 0, 0,  0.), (b'', 0, 0, 0,  0.)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<f8')])
In [70]: for name in res.dtype.names:    # copy by field name
    ...:     res[name] = data[name]

In [71]: res
Out[71]: 
array([(b'a1', 0, 0, 0,  0.1), (b'b2', 1, 2, 3,  4.4)], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S2'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<f8')])
```

Since usually structured arrays have many records, and few fields, copying by field name is relatively fast.

The linked SO cited `matplotlib.mlab.rec_drop_fields(rec, names)`.  This essentially does what I just outlined - make a target with the desired fields, and copy fields by name.

```
newdtype = np.dtype([(name, rec.dtype[name]) for name in rec.dtype.names
                     if name not in names])
```

Comment: Under your usecols` heading, how would you do that if you didn't know what column `id` was in? I Really like your `refunctions` information btw. Nice informative answer.

Comment: I'd have to do an exploratory read (e.g. genfromtxt with limited number of rows) to find the names.  I may be wrong on this, but I imagine most `csv` users know what the column names are before hand.

Comment: Since this was written multifield indexing has changed.  Read the structured arrays docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

This may be new functionality in `numpy` (works in 1.20.2) but you can just slice your named array using a list of names (a tuple of names doesn't work though).

```
data = np.genfromtxt('some_file.csv', names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
# I don't want colums b or d
sliced = data[['a', 'c', 'd']]
```

I notice that you need to eliminate many columns that are named `id`. These columns show up as `['id', 'id_1', 'id_2', ...]` and so on when parsed by `genfromtxt`, so you can use some list comprehension to pick out those column names and make a slice out of them.

```
no_ids = data[[n for n in data.dtype.names if 'id' not in n]]
```

Comment: Multifield indexing existed in 2017 - see my answer.  Implementation details have changed.