# will lambda func be 'cached'/remembered

Tags: python, lambda

`map( lambda x: len(x), aLotOfData)`

I am writing some code similar to above, will it actually be slower if I put in the lambda def in the same line? or I should assign to to a variable f to avoid evolve the lambda def in every iteration or python actually smart enough to cache it?

Comment: thansk bakuriu, my example is kind of over-simplified. the lambda was doing more than just len(). was thinking if there is any significant harm by using lambda as sometime it does have a better readibility

Answer (score 1):

The `lambda` is only evaluated once(converted to a code object), so there's no need of of assigning it to a variable.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def func():
...    map( lambda x: len(x), aLotOfData) 
...    
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (map)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x31c3d30, file "<ipython-input-30-27b0b12b0965>", line 2>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (aLotOfData)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

But as `map` is slow with lambda's so should use a list comprehension or generator expression(if you want an iterator) here.

```
[len(x) for x in aLotOfData]
```

or define a full function, which is more readable:

```
def my_func(x):
   #do something with x
   return something

[my_func(x) for x in aLotOfData]
```

[Which is more preferable to use in Python: lambda functions or nested functions ('def')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134626/which-is-more-preferable-to-use-in-python-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions)

Comment: thanks, but why 'map is slow with lambda' if the lambda is only evaluated once? I thought map is just doing exactly the same as [len(x) for x in aLotOfData] with with a additional func all? I can imagine it is slower (as it is with more stack operation) but it might not be slow? or I am missing something very basis? thanks

Comment: @JohnZ The answer is a little misleading. `[f(x) for x in l]` is only faster than `map(lambda x: f(x), l)` because of the `lambda`, but it's a daft comparison. `map` is always faster than a list comprehension given identical expressions, so `map(f, l)` is faster than `[f(x) for x in l]`, and `map(lambda x: f(x), l)` is faster than `[(lambda x: f(x))(x) for x in l]`.