# Python idiom - whitespace in *arg/**kwargs

Tags: python, wildcard, args, keyword-argument

So I'm trying to understand how the use of * in the lambda example below fits within the [*arg/**kwarg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) Python idioms.

If I create a simple function, summing, that uses sum(*iterable*) to sum a list of numbers, there's at least a couple ways to do it.

```
def summing(*x): return sum(*x)
```

or I've seen other code which uses this version for lambda

```
summing = lambda * x: sum(*x)
```

For the lambda version, I don't really understand how the * symbol fits into the idiom. I'm assuming that it's not meant to be a glob pattern -- so what is it? Is it used elsewhere in Python? (Or is something like "*args" whitespace insensitive?)

(This question started with a little snippet of [code](https://snipt.net/kennethlove/django-absolute-paths-for-settingspy/#disqus_thread) that stumped me.)

Comment: yes, `*args` is whitespace insensitive. `*  args` is the exact same thing.

Comment: Ok. That's a little bit annoying. The trimmed version is preferred?

Comment: PEP 8 hasn't made any proclamations yet, but just about *everyone* uses `*args` and `**kw` (no whitespace between the asterisks and the argument name).

Comment: @iasonas - PEP 8 _has_ stated though that it is a [bad practice](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) to make functions using `lambda` like that.  Instead, you should use `def`, like in your first example.

Comment: Thanks. I've read through PEP 8, and know better than to code the lambda version myself, but I wanted to understand what was going on here. Because PEP 8 is silent about arg/kwarg whitespace, I thought maybe this was something different than *args/**kwargs (or some kind of extension of the idiom)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summing = lambda *x: sum(*x)
```

is basically the same as

```
def summing(*x): return sum(*x)
```

but functions are prefered, as they are [more readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134638/2044940) and a bit [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988012/2044940).

However, you shouldn't use either of the above code snippets. `*x` allows for a variable amount of arguments, only to unpack them for `sum()`.

If you want to pass your `summing()` function arguments like this:

```
summing(1,2,3,4)
```

... use the following code:

```
def summing(*x): return sum(x)
```

---

If you want to give it a sequence instead...

```
summing([1,2,3,4])
```

... use this:

```
def summing(x): return sum(x)
```

---

Your variant...

```
def summing(*x): return sum(*x)
```

... requires a sequence to be passed (like the function above, hence you don't need `*x` twice!), you can't give it `(1,2,3,4)`. `sum()` takes an iterable as first argument, the second is for a start value. `sum(*x)` will throw errors at you.

Comment: speed is not the reason, not to use lambdas. Also, I think `sum` is just an example i.e., the actual usage inside the function doesn't matter. Otherwise `summing = sum` is simpler and more effective.

Comment: ... or even simpler: `sum(...)` without a function alias. BTW: Guido is against lambdas.

Comment: using just `sum` might be incorrect for the same reasons `typedef` exists in C.

Comment: @Andy Hayden fixed [his benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988012/2044940). Now `def` and `lambda` version have essentially the same speed. Though there are other reasons not to use lambdas (that is what I meant in the first comment).