# How a Matlab anonymous function evaluate a matrix?

Tags: python, matlab, lambda

Given the following matlab code:

```
A = reshape (1:9 ,[3 3]);
f = @(x) x^2;
f(A)
```

the output is:

```
A =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

   1   4   7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   2   5   8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   3   6   9  

ans =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    30    66   102                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    36    81   126                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    42    96   150
```

Can you please explain to me how this output is calculated? how the anonymous function is invoked?

I want to write the same program in python.

Is there any compatible function in python which lets me implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to do matrix multiplication or assign anonymous functions?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's the [proper MATLAB term](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: That was suppose to be tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I understand that but the humor will likely be lost on those who do not understand the joke, particularly when it leads off with "that's a pretty lousy anonymous function" and does not terminate with some kind of emote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An anonymous function with a matrix as an input behaves just as the contents normally would if executed from the command line. It does nothing special.

The issue is that you're using `^` which is the [matrix power (`mpower`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) and I believe you are looking for the [*element-wise power* (`power`) which is `.^`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) which in your case would square each element individually.

```
f = @(x)x.^2;
B = f(A);
```

If you want to do the same in Python, you can do exactly this with `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3).T
B = np.power(A, 2)
```

If you want to encaptulate this operation, it's best pratice to put it into it's own function

```
def f(x):
    return np.power(x, 2)

B = f(A)
```

If you named `lambda` (anonymous) function ([this isn't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134638/670206)) you can do:

```
f = lambda x: np.power(x, 2)
B = f(A)
```

Comment: You should probably point out that in Python, you wouldn't (or rather *shouldn't*) do something like `f = lambda x: np.power(x, 2)`. Anonymous functions are *meant to be anonymous*. You would just do `def f(x): return np.power(x, 2)`

Comment: @MaroueneBoubakri Why didn't you include the actual function in your question?

Comment: @maro: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on Python and numpy.  We can't teach you the entire Python syntax here, not to mention the Python syntax and all the numpy array methods.