# How to convert number to time in python?

Tags: python

I need convert number to time.

For example:

I need to convert `1230` to `12:30` or `0730` to `07:30`.

How to convert a number to time in python?

Comment: what's the time for this `3277` number?

Comment: Use DateTime instead

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I get time with json and in the form of api. I need add `:` in number.

Comment: from where you are getting input ?

Comment: write input with its format

Comment: Treat it as as string and insert the `:` if you don't want an actual `time` ?

Comment: Yes - you don't need to keep pinging everyone thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a `function` that takes a `string` and `returns` the `time`.

This can all be done in one line by `slicing` the `string` up to the `minutes` (done with `[:2]`) and then concatenating a `':'` and finally concatenating the `minutes` with `[2:]`.

```
def getTime(t):
    return t[:2] + ':' + t[2:]
```

and some tests to show it works:

```
>>> getTime("1230")
'12:30'
>>> getTime("0730")
'07:30'
>>> getTime("1512")
'15:12'
```

---

Note how the `function` *cannot* take an `integer` and convert this to a `string`, as otherwise entries with leading zeros would fail. E.g. `0730` wouldn't work.

---

Yes, to answer `@AbhishtaGatya`, this could be written using a `lambda` function, but doing so wouldn't be advisable. However:

```
getTime = lambda t: t[:2] + ':' + t[2:]
```

works just the same as above.

Comment: is it better to use a lambda for this or just a function?

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya `lambda` is just a `one-line` way of defining a `function`, it is still just a `function`, so you could definitely do it if you wanted (see the most recent edit).

Comment: why is lambda not advisable? and i think you can fix the interger problem by converting the argument as a string using `str()`

Comment: The reason `lambda` is not advisable can be seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134626/which-is-more-preferable-to-use-in-python-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions). Essentially, if you are assigning a `function` to a `variable` you should use `def` and if creating an anonymous `function` that is 'throw away' (e.g. as a `key` for sorting) you can use `lambda`. As for the `integer` problem, this cannot be fixed easily as you *can't* have an `integer` definition in Python3 with any leading zeros. So even `x = 08` is invalid and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is a *string*, you can do this:

```
number_str = '0730'
time_str = number_str[:2] + ':' + number_str[2:]
print(time_str)  # Output: '07:30'
```

Comment: I would start with `number_str = str(number_str)`, so it works with both, numbers and strings.

Comment: @Piinthesky But, as @Joe Iddon points out, it's impossible to have the _integer_ `0730` — any leading zeroes are truncated, leaving `730`. So your suggestion would result in `number_str = '730'`, not `'0730'`.

Comment: I know. It was just in case a number like `1023` is passed as an argument. But you are right, nobody would use this, because it doesn't work for all time points.

Comment: In fact, adding leading zeros can be done using string formatting: `number_str = '{:0>4}'.format(number)`, which when given `number = 730` or `number = '0730'`  results in `'0730'`.

Comment: Addendum: actually, attempting `number = 0730` does not truncate the leading zero, but throws a `SyntaxError` (in Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert ":" to the  index 2

```
val = 1230
new= ([str(i) for i in str(val)])
new.insert(2,":")

print(''.join(new))
```

**output:**

```
12:30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you only have 4 digits as strings one way is

```
new = '%s:%s'%(string[:2], string[2:])
```

Recommended is however to use the datetime handling within python
[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

t1="1205"
t2="0605PM"
#%I - 12 hour format
print t1,(datetime.strptime(t1,"%I%M")).strftime("%I:%M")
print t2,(datetime.strptime(t2,"%I%M%p")).strftime("%I:%M")

#%H - 24 hour format
print t1,(datetime.strptime(t1,"%I%M")).strftime("%H:%M") 
print t2,(datetime.strptime(t2,"%I%M%p")).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these require 4 digits for your time. This code will add a zero to the front if there are 3 digits. It will check for invalid times.

```
def conv_num_time(time):
num_str = ('{:04}'.format(time))
time_str = num_str[:2] + ':' + num_str[2:]
if int(num_str[:2])>23 or int(num_str[2:])>59:
    print("Invalid time")
else:
    print(time_str)
user_time = int(input(': '))
conv_num_time(user_time)
```