# dictionary with lists custom equality check

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Say, I have two lists:

`a = [1,2,3]`
and `b = [2,3,1]`

If I do a `a == b` it returns `False`,

If I check `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`, it returns `True`.

Now, I have two objects:

`obj1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]}`
and `obj2 = {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': [1, 2]}`

`obj1 == obj2` is True, irrespective of the order of keys.

But if `obj2 = {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': [2, 1]}`

how do I test the equality? Obviously, `obj1 == obj2` returns False. `sorted(obj1)` will have `['a', 'b', 'c']`, so `sorted(obj1) == sorted(obj2)` is kind of waste check.

I should have probably overridden the equality method for the object, or use some library. Is, is there any way to write idiomatic python code for deep equality?

Comment: so what is your definition of equality for this?

Comment: I need `obj1 == obj2` return True, if `obj1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]}` and `obj2 = {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': [2, 1]}`

Comment: `sorted(['a', 'b', 'c'])` isn't as wasteful as you might think since Python's timsort uses a clever hybrid sorting algorithm that performs well on already sorted (or almost sorted) data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` each element in the dict if it is of type `list` and then compare

```
>>> def sorted_element_dict(d):
...     return {k:sorted(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k,v in d.items()}
...
>>> sorted_element_dict(obj1) == sorted_element_dict(obj2)
True
```

Comment: Also use `isinstance` instead of `type`.

Comment: @timgeb. I would prefer `sorted` as the list may contain unhashable elements

Comment: @timgeb And the list may contain duplicates (which sets cannot)

Comment: @timgeb, convert to set is wrong because sets cannot have duplicates while list can do

Comment: @timgeb. Changed `type` check to `isinstance`. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is no reason to use `lambda` here, it should be `def`

Comment: @Chris_Rands. I believe `lambda` vs `def` is a personal preference

Comment: @Sunitha If you're assigning to `lambda` you're doing it wrong, `lambda` functions should be anonymous, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134626/which-is-more-preferable-to-use-in-python-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions

Comment: @Chris_Rands.. Ok you win :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in an equality check, consider using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all). You could just apply a custom comparator to all the dictionary values:

```
def check_equal(d1, d2):
    if d1.keys() != d2.keys():
        return False
    return all(sorted(v) == sorted(d2[k]) if isinstance(v, list) else v == d2[k] for k, v in d1.items())
```

A more elegant way might be to factor out the comparator into a separate function and check against something more general, like [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence):

```
def check_equal(d1, d2):
    if d1.keys() != d2.keys():
        return False
    def cmp(v1, v2):
        if isinstance(v1, Sequence) and isinstance(v2, sequence):
            return sorted(v1) == sorted(v2)
        return v1 == v2
    return all(cmp(v, d2[k]) for k, v in d1.items())
```

This has the advantage of *not* storing all the intermediate sorted products. If, on the other hand, you need to do the comparison frequently, it may be better to transform your dictionaries before using regular `==`:

```
def normalize(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, Sequence):
            d[k] = sorted(v)
```

Notice that I used a loop instead of a comprehension here. That way, your dictionary is transformed in-place, rather than allocating a whole new hash table.