# It is Good Practice to Assign Lambda Expression to a Variable in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

Is it considered as good practice to assign lambda expressions in C++ to a variable?
I know from python, that it isn't good practice

[Which is more preferable to use: lambda functions or nested functions ('def')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134626/which-is-more-preferable-to-use-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-def)

which makes perfect sense to me, because it makes no sense to give an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) a name. However, I have seen very often in C++ that lambda is assigned to a variable, like here for example

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view

Is this considered as good practice in C++? From this post here

[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

I conclude, it can be also seen as very convenient way to define functors. So it looks like lambda is in C++ considered as more than just an anonymous function.

Comment: Its good practice to make your code readable. If assigning a lambda to a variable makes it more readable, do it.

Comment: Note that the question you linked asks for better choice between two options: lambda or nested function. C++ doesn't allow nested function definitions, so a lambda is the only possibility for named definition of another function.

Comment: Opinion based perhaps.

Comment: note that python has style guides that come with the language. C++ doesnt have that. There are many things considered as "pythonic" or "non pythonic" which are merely  based on some style guide which is based on opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it usually is. It improves your code by making it more readable. Of course, don't use lambda for lambda's own sake.